# How to call __name__=='__main__' from a method in class?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to call main function `__name__=='__main__'` from method. How can i call it?

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = GraphWin('Tic-Tac-Toe', 500, 700, autoflush=False)  # give title and dimensions
    win.setBackground('Grey')
    win.items = []
    g1 = Game()
    g1.choice_player_button()
```

Comment: There is *no `main` function* in the code you've provided. Note, `main`, is not any sort of special name in Python. In any case, there is no function defined here.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this:

```py
print("Hello")

print("__name__ value: ", __name__)


def main():
    print("python main function")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, basically, wrap all stuff you want to execute on script run inside the `main` function. In that way, you can call that part of code from every other place in your script.

In your case, that would look like this:

```py
def main():
    win = GraphWin('Tic-Tac-Toe', 500, 700, autoflush=False) # give title and dimensions
    win.setBackground('Grey')
    win.items = []
    g1 = Game()
    g1.choice_player_button()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to call main function `__name__=='__main__'` from method. How can I call it?

You can't, because it's not a function.

The proper solution is to move the code into a function. Then, you can easily do what you want.

```
# somefile.py

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Tic-Tac-Toe', 500, 700, autoflush=False)  # give title and dimensions
    win.setBackground('Grey')
    win.items = []
    g1 = Game()
    g1.choice_player_button()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

From some other file you can then do something like this:

```
from somefile import main
main()
```